Is there a cutoff to ask to be redshirted?
My son is an incoming freshman on a D1 soccer team.
Is there a cutoff to ask to be redshirted?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For those of you who don't know what redshirting is, it is defined as:

Redshirt, in United States college athletics, is a delay or suspension of an athlete's participation in order to lengthen their period of eligibility.

I'm going to assume that this question asks about GPA, as that just makes the most sense. In that case, yes, there is a cutoff, and that is 2.3, according to this wikipedia article.

In 2016, a new status could be applied to prospective student athletes, dubbed an academic redshirt. That year, the NCAA started enforcing new, stricter admissions requirements for incoming athletic freshmen. Under these new requirements, a student athlete who meets a school's own academic admission requirements but does not meet the NCAA requirement of a 2.3 GPA across four years, may enter school as an academic redshirt. This student can receive an athletic scholarship and practice with the team, but may not participate in competition.

(Bolding mine)
In terms of a time cutoff, generally, there isn’t a specific deadline to be redshirted.
